# How to create PACT file for GET endpoint which returns HTML with changing url?

Tags: scala, pact

I have created a consumer's pact file which I need to validate at provider's end. My API is a GET endpoint and when I hit the endpoint, I receive a HTML snippet which holds another endpoint called inside an HTML. The endpoint which I am redirected to contains parameters which will change every time I hit my URL. Consider trace-id as one of the param, it will be different when I create my pact file and when I hit my endpoint at the time of validation of that pact file. 
I am blocked to use bodyRegexRules as there is no key to which my value is mapped.

I wish to validate my consumer pact file successfully wither by some dynamic creation of the param or bypassing the validation for that param.

I have tried mapping my body(HTML) to my user defined data type. I have also tried using the complete HTML as a body.
I have tried removing the body param resulting in successful validation.

```
"body" : "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />\n    <title>---my title---</title>\n</head>\n<body onload=\"window.location = '---my url---'\">\n\n</body>\n</html>",
```

In this body tag of my pact file I have a HTML page where where my url hold params which will change when I validate my query at provider side.